# How can I allow jQuery draggable items to be dragged out of a div with a scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's what I would like to achieve. At the top of my page is a row of images.  The row of images is wider than the page, so should have a scrollbar underneath. I want to be able to drag an image out of the container div onto a div below.

The problem that I'm having is that, as soon as the initial image is in a div with a scrollbar, I can no longer drag it out of that div.  The div just gets a vertical scrollbar when I try to drag the image down.

How do I work around this?

My current set-up is very basic:

```
<div id="library">
  <div id="assets">
     <div class="assetitem"><img src="..." /></div>
     <div class="assetitem"><img src="..." /></div>
     <div class="assetitem"><img src="..." /></div>
     <div class="assetitem"><img src="..." /></div>
     <div class="assetitem"><img src="..." /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css sets a width on the library div, with overflow-x: scroll.  The assets div has a width of 10000px, to allow all images to fit in.

The draggable is applied to each assetitem.

When I try to drag an assetitem out of the library div, it just expands in height and scrolls.

Comment: Have you try to set the [scroll option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-scroll) to false on assetitems?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that.  Yes, I have revert: true, scroll: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be stuck using a helper, because as you have seen dragging with `overflow:scroll` causes the div to scroll:

```
$(".assetitem").draggable({helper:"clone"});​
```

Note:  I tried playing with the `appendTo` option, but I never got it working with the overflow set.